# Turning an elliptic curve over C into a complex torus

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I have been reading a lot about the Weierstrass $\wp$ function and I understand the parameterization of an elliptic curve with the elliptic function( i.e. $x=\wp(z)$ and $y=\wp^\prime(z)$). I would like to parameterize my own elliptic curve, but I'm running into some difficulty. For example, with the curve $y^2=x^3+2x^2−3x$, all I want to do is find $\wp(z)$ and $\wp^\prime(z)$ for some $z$ (should I use $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$?) and I would like to compute $g_2$ and $g_3$. I guess I could have saved some space by just saying that I want to find a parameterization between $y^2=x^3+2x^2−3x$ and $y^2=4x^3−g_2x−g_3$. Is this trivial and I'm just missing something? I know Sage will handle finding at least the periods.

Comment: Dear Brent, I'm not really understanding what your problem is. If you can find the periods, which, as you say, Sage can do, then you have the lattice, and once you have the lattice, you can easily evaluate $\wp$ and $\wp'$ at any desired point. As for finding $g_2$ and $g_3$, you can basically read them off your equation (once it's in Weierstrass form). It seems to me the only problem you're having is putting your equation in Weierstrass form? Regards,

Comment: No, I knew how to put it in Weierstrass form. Basically, given any lattice, I just needed a simple way of computing g_2 and g_3 (which Pari/GP will do). It was more of a simple computation question than a theory one.

Comment: Well, you can do it straight from the definition. If you have the lattice $\Lambda$, then $g_2 = 60 \sum_{\omega \in \Lambda} \omega^{-4}$ and $g_3 = 140 \sum_{\omega \in \Lambda} \omega^{-6}$.

Answer (score 5):

Quite likely I am misunderstanding what you want to do, but if you have $y^2=x^3+2x^2-3x$, you can use the [depression substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Reduction_to_a_depressed_cubic) $x=t-\frac23$ to yield the new cubic

$$y^2=t^3-\frac{13}{3}t+\frac{70}{27}$$

With the further substitution $t=\sqrt[3]{4}u$, we have

$$y^2=4u^3-\frac{13\sqrt[3]{4}}{3}u+\frac{70}{27}$$

which means we have the invariants $g_2=\frac{13\sqrt[3]{4}}{3}$ and $g_3=-\frac{70}{27}$ (with respect to the new coordinates).

As already noted, from these invariants, you can express the periods in terms of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind (see e.g. the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/23.6.ii) for the needed formulae), which is most efficiently evaluated with the arithmetic-geometric mean iteration.

---

As Brent notes in the comments, some take the Weierstrass form to have a leading coefficient of $1$ instead of $4$; that is, the standard form looks like

$$y^2=x^3-g_2 x-g_3$$

In this case, one just performs the depression substitution, yielding $g_2=\dfrac{13}{3}$.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I wanted to know. I found out a while ago that PARI can compute the invariants based of the periods (which Sage will find). My main question should have been this this: can I calculate the modular invariants without trying to compute them from an Eisenstein series. Like I said, I found out PARI can do this for me, but I like your substitution method as well. Thank you

Comment: Well, if you're already starting from the cubic, then yes, getting the invariants is a snap; there will always be a Möbius transformation to convert any cubic into Weierstrass form, from which you can read off invariants. If all you have are the two periods, then you can't avoid theta functions/Eisenstein series...

Comment: I just took a second look at this. I got the same value for g3 but 4.333333 for g2. Any ideas how that happened? I look back at my work

Comment: @Brent, I suppose that might mean that Sage has a different convention for the "Weierstrass form" than the one I am accustomed to. I seem to recall having seen formulations where the cubic term has a coefficient of $1$ instead, and in that case, the invariant $g_2$ should indeed be $13/3$. You should check the docs yourself, as I've no access to the software you're using.

Comment: You're right, I used a form where the cubic term has a coefficient of 1. Case solved

Answer (score 3):

This was way too long for a comment, but I'm not sure it's really an answer since I'm basically saying "I don't think this is trivial"--I hope that it helps at least a little.

As far as I know this isn't trivial. First of all, because the computations just work out nicer let's assume that you are given a curve in the standard Weierstrass form $y^2=4x^3-Ax-B$. Now, finding $\wp$ would be trivial if you knew *which* lattice $L$ satisfies $g_2(L)=A$ and $g_3(L)=B$. That said,the existence of such a lattice really comes down to the surjectivity of $j$ which, at least the proof I know, is proven using the argument principle to show that it can't not assume a value in $\mathbb{C}$.

Well, let's suppose for a second that this wasn't too hard, that you were actually able to effectively solve $j(z)=c$ for $c\in\mathbb{C}$. We then find $z_0$ such that $j(z_0)=c$ where

$$c:=1728\frac{A^3}{A^3-27B^2}$$

This should look right for if $L$ is a lattice such that $g_2(L)=A$ and $g_3(L)=B$ then $j(L)$ would be exactly $c$. Well, as I'm sure you know if we let $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}z_0$ then $j(\Lambda)=j(z_0)=c$. Now, one of $g_2(\Lambda)$ or $g_3(\Lambda)$ must be non-zero since $\Delta(\Lambda)\ne 0$, let's assume without loss of generality that $g_2(\Lambda)\ne 0$ (it should be obvious, after what I'm about to say, how to proceed if it is actually $g_3(\Lambda)$ that is nonzero). Now, from this we can find some scaling factor $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $g_2(\lambda\Lambda)=\lambda^{-4}g_2(\Lambda)=A$. Since $\lambda\Lambda$ and $\Lambda$ have the same $j$-invariant we can solve

$$1728\frac{g_2(\lambda L)^3}{g_2(\lambda\Lambda)^3-27g_2(\lambda\Lambda)^2}=j(\lambda\Lambda)=j(\Lambda)=1728\frac{A^3}{A^3-27B^2}$$

(using the fact that $g_2(\lambda\Lambda)=A$) to get that, in fact, $g_3(\lambda\Lambda)^2=B^2$ and thus $g_3(\lambda\Lambda)=\pm B$. Either way we're fine though. Namely, if $g_3(\lambda\Lambda)=B$ we're done, and if not then we can replace $\lambda\Lambda$ with $i\lambda\Lambda$ and check that

$$g_2(i\lambda\Lambda)=i^4g_2(\lambda\Lambda)=A$$

and

$$g_3(i\lambda \Lambda)=i^6g_3(\lambda\Lambda)=-(-B)=B$$

So, in either case we have found our desired lattice which allows us to find $\wp$.

Now, the point of the above is that the only roadblock to explicitly and easily finding the lattice $\Lambda$ for which $y^2=4x^3-Ax-B$ is just the plane curve associated to $\wp_\Lambda$ is the ability to solve the equation $j(z)=c$. Now, I am by no means expert (not even close!) enough to say that there is no simple/algorithmic way to solving $j(z)=c$, but the only methods I know to even proving that $j(z)=c$ are purely existential (as I said, it's just showing that $j(z)\ne c$ can't happen otherwise a certain contour integral wouldn't come out right).

Anyways, while the above isn't exactly optimistic, it shows you that you can reduce the problem to a problem about whether the surjectivity proof of the $j$-invariant can be made constructive, which (hopefully) may be easily googleable/amenable to search.

Comment: Thanks! I started to think about using a relation on j-invariant shortly after I posted this question. It seems like the major problem comes when trying to calculate g2 and g3. The periods w1 and w2 can be calculated(Sage does it quickly, but you can also use the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean). Now I know that g2 and g3 depend on w1 and w2, but that still doesn't make it so easy to calculate or solve for.

Comment: Hi Alex! +1. Here's perhaps a more direct way of finding the lattice $\Lambda$ associated to $y^2=4x^3-Ax-B$. Finding this lattice is equivalent to finding the periods of the curve, which are given by two elliptic integrals of the form $\int dx/y$ (with suitably chosen endpoints). Anyways, maybe I'm not understanding OP's question properly.