# How to obtaining the lattice corresponding to an elliptic curve

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions, vector-lattices

Let $C$ be a complex elliptic curve given by the quation $y^2=4x^3-g_2 x -g_3$.
How do I find the lattice $\Lambda$ such that $C \cong \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$?
I need the lattice (and corresponding Weierstrass $P$ function) but I don't know how to get it explicitly from the elliptic invaiants $g_2$ and $g_3$.

Comment: The converse question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291245

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309882/

Answer (score 5):

The generators of the lattice are given by line integrals of the differential dx/y. See Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", Chapter 6, in particular Proposition 5.2.

If you want to know how this is *actually* done, I'd suggest Cohen's "A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory", Chapter 7, in particular Algorithm 7.4.7.