# Elliptic curve with prescribed lattice

Tags: elliptic-curves

It's well known that there is a connection between elliptic curves and lattices. To establish such a connection one needs to use Eisenstein series.

How one can one write down the *explicit* equation of an elliptic curve knowing its lattice?

For example, what is the equation of the elliptic curve with lattice $<1,i>$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be a lattice. Then the explicit equation of the associated elliptic curve is given by
$$
E_L\colon y^2=4x^3-g_2(L)x-g_3(L).
$$
Here the Eisenstein series are given by
$$
g_2(L)=60\sum_{L^{\times}}\frac{1}{\omega^4},\quad g_3(L)=140\sum_{L^{\times}}\frac{1}{\omega^6}.
$$
If we can compute these series explicitly, then we have an explicit equation of the elliptic curve. For standard lattices, like the Gaussian lattice $L=\mathbb{Z}[i]$, or the hexagonal lattice these series are well known and have been computed. For the Gaussian lattice with basis $1,i$ the result is
$$
g_2(L)=\frac{\Gamma(1/4)^8}{16\pi^2}>0,\quad g_3(L)=0.
$$
For the lattice $L=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$ we obtain the curve $y^2=4x^3-g_3(L)$.

Comment: The link is now [this one](https://www2.bc.edu/mark-reeder/815hw4.pdf).

Comment: @Watson Thank you! I have updated the link.

Comment: These links are invalid now.

Comment: @buoyant Yes, you are right, one should give a reference from a book. I am sure one can find one, since the result is quite well known. I have taken out the bad link.

Answer (score 3):

I think that, in general, this is a tough question. If $\Lambda$ is a lattice in $\mathbb C$, then the elliptic curve $\mathbb C/\Lambda$ has an equation of the form $y^2=x^3+g_2(\Lambda)x+g_3(\Lambda)$ where $$g_2(\Lambda)=60\sum_{0\neq \omega\in \Lambda}\frac{1}{\omega^4}$$ and
$$g_3(\Lambda)=140\sum_{0\neq \omega\in \Lambda}\frac{1}{\omega^6}$$

If $\Lambda=\langle 1,i\rangle$, it is an easy exercise to check that $g_3(\Lambda)=0$. Therefore the elliptic curve $\mathbb C/\Lambda$ has j-invariant $1728$ and thus is isomorphic to the curve $y^2=x^3+x$.

Comment: Could you give a hint to "easy exercise " $g_3(\Lambda)=0$ , please? 
How did you determine the value of $j$-invariant ?

Comment: @user44636 $g_3(L)=0$ for the Gaussian lattice $\langle 1,i\rangle$ is proved on page $1$ of my link; the $j$-invariant of the curve $y^2=4x^3-ax-b$ is $j=\frac{1728a^3}{a^3-27b^2}$.

Comment: Does $\Bbb C / \Lambda$ indeed correspond to the curve $y^2=x^3+g_2(\Lambda)x+g_3(\Lambda)$ ? For me, it's rather $y^2 = 4x^3 - g_2(\Lambda)x - g_3(\Lambda)$.