# What is a lattice of elliptic curve $y^2＝x^3-x$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, integer-lattices, elliptic-functions

It is well known that isomorphism class of elliptic curve and lattice up to homeothetic corresponds bijectively.

But I don't have concrete examples. Can we figure out lattice from given weierstrass equation?

For example,

> What is a lattice of elliptic curve $y^2＝x^3-x$ ?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766229, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291245, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309882/. I guess the lattice should be $\Bbb Z[i]$. Note that your curve has CM by this order in $\Bbb Q(i)$.

Comment: note that (1,0), (0,0), and (-1,0) are part of the lattice - am I interpreting your question correctly?

Comment: Also note that x selection is limited to be "far" from prime.

Comment: @Moti, you have noted points on the curve $E$. However, OP is asking not about this - there is a theorem that an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ has a complex analytic group isomorphism with the Riemann surface $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ for some rank $2$ $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{C}$; OP wants to know what $\Lambda$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curve you asked about ($y^2 = x^3 - x$) is [LMFDB 32.a3](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/32/a/3). Here the Weierstrass
invariants are $\,g_2=-1/4,\, g_3=0\,$ and this is known as the
pseudo-lemniscate case. See [DLMF 23.5.iv](https://dlmf.nist.gov/23.5.iv)
for some details. The lattice for this curve is a square lattice with side length
$$\Gamma(1/4)^2/\sqrt{2\pi}=5.244115108584239620\dots$$
and the period parallelogram is a
square one of whose diagonals is along the real axis.